# Getting NullPointerException while sending data from activity to fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have implemented the fragment in android.
Now we try to send the data from activity to the fragment. But while sending the data we are getting the *NullPointerException* in `*onCreateView*` method of fragment.

Following  code of Activity.

```
 setContentView(R.layout.fragment_1);
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTranstction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        Fragment1 f1 = new Fragment1();
                    String text1 = "prakash";
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("sessionName", text1);
        f1.setArguments(bundle);
        ft.add(R.id.frag1, f1);
        ft.commit();
```

Following code of Fragment:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = this.getArguments().getString("sessionName");    
    TextView sessionTitle = (TextView) getView()
            .findViewById(R.id.session1);
    sessionTitle.setText(strtext);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
}
```

what is the mistake i did, because of that i am getting *NullPointerException*, please help

Comment: change the string getting code to onActivityCreate() override method. its come after the oncreateview

Comment: for communication between Activity and Fragment watch this : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321449/android-navigation-drawer-unable-to-settext-in-a-fragment-from-mainactivity/24322359#24322359

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:-

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    String strtext = this.getArguments().getString("sessionName");    
    TextView sessionTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.session1);
    sessionTitle.setText(strtext);
    return view;
}
```

your not getting view and try to set value on textview.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
 TextView sessionTitle = (TextView) getView()
        .findViewById(R.id.session1);
```

`getView()` returns null in your case. So `sessionTitle` is null and when you call `setText()` on null you get `NUllPointerException`.

SO change to

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = (VIew)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false); 
    // inflate tha layout
    String strtext = this.getArguments().getString("sessionName");   
    // get the string  
    TextView sessionTitle = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.session1);
     // initialize textview or initialize it in onActivityCreated using getView
    sessionTitle.setText(strtext);
    // set text to textview
    return view
}
```

You can use `getView().findViewById(id)` in `onActivityCreated()`

Answer (score 0):

while getting the id of textview you are getting **nullpointer exception**,because of using getview(),getview is  used when we get the id in onActivityCreated method(). just change getview() to view will remove this exception.just  chnage :

```
TextView sessionTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.session1);
```