# Calling new Activity from fragment activity

Tags: android, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

This seems to be weird problem,

Scenario:

I have a FragmentActivity (FragActy) - having which has TabHost
FragActy starts a child Fragment (child_Fragment_1)
childFrag_1 starts another child (child_Fragment_2)
childFrag_2 Starts A new Activity (newActivity) - which is a simple android activity.

good so far,

But when I click back from newActivity instead of showing child_Fragment_2, Im going to child_Fragment_1.

The problem is weird because, when in lastActivity, if I change screen orientation **Once** and then press back the behavior is normal, i.e, child_Fragment_1 is shown.
Again if I rotate twice I'm going to child_Fragment_1.

Image for scenario description below.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: See the following link, You can understand how to communicate between Activity - Fragment and Fragment - Fragment

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321449/android-navigation-drawer-unable-to-settext-in-a-fragment-from-mainactivity/24322359#24322359

Answer (score 0):

Try this, clear the fragment stack when you are on fragment 2 using this

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
   for(int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
    fm.popBackStack();
}
```

and before launching the fragment activity add the fragment to backstack like this:

```
ft.addToBackStack(null);
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: you wellcome :) hope it helps

Comment: Hi Syed, Thanks for the reply. I didn't seem to understood though, U mean When i come to childFragment_2 clear off the fragment backstack? Thanks(Sorry hit enter it got posted :P)

Comment: yes here is what you have to do before you launch your fragment activity :
1) clear the stack
2) push your desired fragment which you wana show on back press into stack
3) start the activity

Comment: Ya I will try your solution, meanwhile I tried recreating project with similar setup with similar fragmentActivity and child fragments, Seems to be working fine - even without handling onSaveInstances anywhere, wherein actual project has onSaveinstances handled.